# Magical Record - losing my Entity information

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I have an app that had a TableView with customer information.

If a click on a cell I load the detail of this customer.

I'm using Magical Record to manage all my entities.

**What I'm doing:**

> 1) Load all the CUSTOMER entity on the viewDidLoad of my TableView.
>   2) User click to see the detail of the customer
>   3) Pass to the ViewController of the detail the object that represent the entity CUSTOMER (only one).

Everything works well.

**The problem is, if the user select to reload the TableView I do this:**

> 1) Go to the API to get all the customers
>   2) [Customer truncateAll]
>   3) Create all the entities back on CoreData
>   5) [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreAndWait]
>   6) Reload tableview

BUT, if the user click to see the detail of the Customer during this process, the following ViewController show the customer information correctly for a while. Then after 
[Customer truncateAll] occurs all the information dies.

How can I prevent this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `NSFetchedResultController` to listen for your `Customer` entity changes. When your API call finishes and you create proper entities somewhere else in your app, you'll be notified in the controller about those changes and then you can reload the data. If you're not familiar with this concept look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

Comment: I've got it. The problemn is,how can I identify the same customer i'm viewing? Remember, i'm doing 2) [Customer truncateAll] right after the download it's done